# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'transitionTo'

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

After upgrading kineticjs from 4.0.5 to 4.5.1, I get

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'transitionTo'`

Following code works with the previous version:

```
gameLayer.transitionTo({
        duration: '0.5',
        opacity: 1,
        callback: function() {
            intervalId = setInterval(reDraw, 33);
            isInteractive = true;

        }
    });
```

Whats the the alternative function for `transitionTo` in `4.5.1`

## UPDATE

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/459) over Github, according to [the guy](https://github.com/ericdrowell) `transitionTo` has been removed and it  is replaced by [`Tween`](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Tween.html)

Regards,

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `onFinish` attribute as below :

```
 var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect, 
    duration: 1,
    x: 400,
    y: 30,
    rotation: Math.PI * 2,
    opacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 6,
    scaleX: 1.5,
    onFinish: function() {console.log('onFinish');}
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is TweenLite. It has much more functionalities than the classic Kinetic transitions so they have been deprecated and TweenLite is fully adapted to KineticJS shapes.

Here is a tutorial that shows us how to use these transitions.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-linear-transition-tutorial-with-kineticjs/

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    opacity: 0.2
  });

  layer.add(rect);
  stage.add(layer);

  var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
    node: rect, 
    duration: 1,
    x: 400,
    y: 30,
    rotation: Math.PI * 2,
    opacity: 1,
    strokeWidth: 6,
    scaleX: 1.5
  });

  // start tween after 20 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    tween.play();
  }, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks, a bunch. I saw tween but was hesitated to go with. and What about the callbacks then? are callbacks supported in tweens